# Confusion regarding [NSDate date]

Tags: iphone, nsdate

[NSDate date] returns GMT on simulator... what time does it return on the device... ? And also  how can I get the simulator time programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns the current date and time. NSDate is timezone-independent. The [`-description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description) of NSDate may be in GMT, but it's not guarenteed.

> The representation is not guaranteed to remain constant across different releases of the operating system. To format a date, you should use a date formatter object instead.

If you want to display or parse a date in a different timezone, use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) (and modify its timezone/locale property) or use [`-descriptionWithLocale:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate).

```
NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale]
NSLog(@"current locale = %@", [currentLocale localeIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"date = %@", [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:currentLocale];
```

Comment: on my simulator it is returning the GMT time.. 12:36:33 whereas the actual time my simulator is showing 6:09pm .. :O

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: How do you print the time?

Comment: NSLog(@"nsdate  %@",[NSDate date]);

Comment: and if I use..   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"the date %@",theDate); this gives me proper value (my current system time), even though I did not specify the time zone...

Comment: So by default the dateformatter takes currentLocale... right?

Answer (score 1):

NSDate is timezone-independent.  When you get the description with `description` it displays a timezone but that's entirely "informational", and, to my knowledge there's no way to set or access that timezone info (other than `description`).  The value stored in the NSDate object is (supposed to be) GMT/UTC (though of course it can't tell if you're feeding it the wrong time).

To get the simulator's understanding of the current time and date use `[NSDate date]`.  Format it (if need be) with NSDateFormatter.

Comment: and if I use.. NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; NSString *theDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; NSLog(@"the date %@",theDate); this gives me proper value (my current system time), even though I did not specify the time zone..

Comment: When you do that, NSDateFormatter implicitly picks up the current timezone and locale.  You can explicitly set those things if you want something different.

Comment: Ok... then how can I get a nsdate object which contains my system date... ?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava -- Like I said, `[NSDate date]`.